# Magento 2 | Add tracking number in the shipment already created

Tags: magento2, orders, shipment, shipment-tracking

On the Magento2 backend in the shipment tab I noticed that it is possible to add a second tracking number even when the shipment is already created.
The problem is that when you click "add" and try to send the tracking information it doesn't save you the new tracking number. How come?

Is there a way on Magento to add and save a new tracking number even when the shipment is already created?